# voicevox_coreのサンプルをC++(Windows Visual Studio)で実行しようとしたら「～の識別子が定義されていない」というエラーが出て失敗する

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

## 問題の概要

voicevox_coreのサンプルを実行しようとC++(Windows Visual Studio)の環境で[Windows C++ のサンプルプロジェクト](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox_core/tree/main/example/cpp/windows)のREADMEを参考にして進めていた所、配布されていたサンプルプログラムの「simple_tts.cpp」というファイルで「～の識別子が定義されていない」などのエラーが43件表示される
後述しますが、複数のバージョンで検証しました、しかし一番解決したいバージョンは0.14.5です

## 試したこと

windows11 home ver.22H2
システムの種類 64bitOS,x64ベースプロセッサ

Githubのレポジトリをクローンしてexample/cpp/windowsにあるREADME.mdを参照

説明にあるとおり[Releases](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox_core/releases/tag/0.14.5)から「voicevox_core-windows-x64-cpu-{バージョン}.zip」をダウンロード
説明にあるとおりopen_jtalk_dic_utf_8-1.11をダウンロード
説明にあるダウンローダーは未使用

[Releases](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox_core/releases/tag/0.14.5)のバージョンでエラーが表示されたため以下のバージョンでも検証
voicevox_core-windows-x64-cpu-0.14.1.zip
voicevox_core-windows-x64-cpu-0.14.4.zip
voicevox_core-windows-x64-cpu-0.14.5.zip
voicevox_core-windows-x64-cpu-0.15.0-preview.16.zip

その他、READMEには「レポジトリをクローンしろ」とは書かれていないため単体の「windows_example.sln」を空のフォルダに移して、Visual Studioで開きましたがREADME通りに「bin」フォルダも「lib」フォルダも生成されませんでした

### 結果

0.15.0以外のバージョン全てで２回目のビルドで「voicevox_core.h」を「データが損なわれるからUnicode形式のファイルにしろ」といった内容の警告が出たため「UTF-16LE」にして保存、以降の警告は表示されませんでした

0.15.0ではmodelフォルダが無いため「model-0.15.0-preview.16.zip」を解凍したものをmodelフォルダとして扱いました

0.14.1, 0.14.4, 0.14.5のバージョンは全て２回目のビルドで失敗しました
エラーの内容は下の画像の通りです

２回目のビルドで失敗した場合「voicevox_core.lib」の場所を確認してくださいと書かれていましたが、フォルダ構造は合っています。なので全てのフォルダに「voicevox_core.lib」をコピーして配置、再度ビルドしましたが結果は変わりませんでした。

0.15.0では２回目のビルドが成功してexeが生成されましたが、「ローカル Windows デバッガー」を押した所「バンドルされていない例外」というエラーが発生しました

画像は0.14.5でビルドしたときのエラー一覧です
[image: 0.14.5でビルドしたときのエラー一覧です]

## 最後に

私は無知ですが、考えられる手は打ちました
しかし、なぜREADMEの通りに行かなかったのか分かりません
どうすればREADMEの通りにC++(Windows Visual Studio)環境で合成された音声を再生できますか？

Comment: [mainブランチのサンプル](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox_core/tree/main/example/cpp/windows)とvoicevox_core-windows-x64-cpu-0.14.5.zipの組み合わせでビルドしようとしていませんか？mainブランチではなく、[0.14.5タグのソース](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox_core/releases/tag/0.14.5)と組み合わせる必要がありるようです。それでもWindows版はビルドエラーになりますが。[Unix版のsimple_tts.cppとコミットログ](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox_core/tree/0.14.5/example/cpp/unix)を見ると、Unix版だけ新API(voicevox_core)用に変更されているようですので、Unix版だとビルドできるのかもしれません。

Comment: [0.15.0-preview.16](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox_core/releases/tag/0.15.0-preview.16)なら、Windows版でもビルドできます。